# Global Tate Duality Exercise in Neukirch

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, galois-cohomology

For $K$ a $\mathfrak p$-adic number field, local Tate duality yields a non-degenerate pairing

$$H^1(K, \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z) \times H^1(K, \mu_n) \longrightarrow \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z,$$

where $\mu_n$ is the group of $n$-th roots of unity, given by $$(\chi, a) \mapsto \chi((a, \bar K|K)).$$

Here $H^1(K, A)$ stands for $H^1(\operatorname{Gal}(\bar K|K), A)$, $\chi$ is a character $\chi: \operatorname{Gal}(\bar K|K) \longrightarrow \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, $a$ lies in $K^\times / K^{\times n}$, and $(a, \bar K|K)$ is the local Artin symbol.

If $n$ doesn't divide the characteristic of the residue field of $K$ then the orthogonal complement of the unramified cohomology $H^1_{nr}(K, \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z) = H^1(\operatorname{Gal}(\tilde K|K), \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)$ is $H^1_{nr}(K, \mu_n) = H^1(\operatorname{Gal}(\tilde K|K), \mu_n).$

Now for a number field $K$, this gives us a non-degenerate pairing of locally compact groups $$\prod'_{\mathfrak{p}} H^1(K_{\mathfrak{p}}, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \times \prod'_{\mathfrak{p}} H^1(K_{\mathfrak{p}}, \mu_n) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$$

given by $$(\chi, \alpha) = \sum_{\mathfrak{p}} \chi_{\mathfrak{p}}(\alpha_{\mathfrak{p}}, \bar{K_{\mathfrak{p}}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}),$$

where the restricted products are taken with respect to the unramified cohomology groups defined above.

It turns out that the images of $$H^1(K, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \prod'_{\mathfrak{p}} H^1(K_{\mathfrak{p}}, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$$

and

$$H^1(K, \mu_n) \rightarrow \prod'_{\mathfrak{p}} H^1(K_{\mathfrak{p}}, \mu_n)$$

are mutual orthogonal complements with respect to the global pairing.

So far, so good. Now given the above, Neukirch set the following exercise on p. 404 of *Algebraic Number Theory*:

If $S$ is a finite set of places of $K$, then the map

$$H^1(K, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \prod'_{\mathfrak{p} \in S} H^1(K_{\mathfrak{p}}, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$$

is surjective if and only if the map

$$H^1(K, \mu_n) \rightarrow \prod'_{\mathfrak{p} \notin S} H^1(K_{\mathfrak{p}}, \mu_n)$$

is injective.

I know this can be proved using Tate-Poitou Duality as in Neukirch-Schmidt-Wingberg, but I have made no progress trying to prove this given only the facts outlined above. I would appreciate any and every hint.